# Multiple exe in batch file with txt as arguments

Tags: batch-file

I have a txt file with a text for each line, this text must be passed to an exe file by using -p which creates a new file which name is given by -f

```
test1.exe -p line1 -f line1.config
```

the config file is then passed as argument as follows

```
test2.exe line1.config line1.bin
```

I'm trying to automatized this process using batch for windows since i would like to achieve

file.txt

```
line1
line2
line3
line4
```

and so

```
test1.exe -p line1 -f line1.config
test1.exe -p line2 -f line2.config
test1.exe -p line3 -f line3.config
test1.exe -p line4 -f line4.config
test2.exe line1.config line1.bin
test2.exe line2.config line2.bin
test2.exe line3.config line3.bin
test2.exe line4.config line4.bin
del line1.config
del line2.config
del line3.config
del line4.config
```

could you  give me a suggestion?

SOLUTION:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('type file.txt') do (
    test1.exe -p %%a -f %%a.config
    test2.exe %%a.config %%a.bin
    del %%a.config
)
```

Comment: read the output of `for /?`

Comment: how do i do that? i've tried 

FOR /F %%a IN (file.txt) DO
 test1.exe -p %%a -f %%a.config
 test2.exe %%a.config %%a.bin

but i get wrong syntax

Comment: looks good. Remember: `%%a` is batch file syntax. If you do it directly on command line, use `%a` only.

Comment: please don't put your solution into the question. Create an answer instead and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('type file.txt') do (
    test1.exe -p %%a -f %%a.config
    test2.exe %%a.config %%a.bin
    del %%a.config
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want the names of your config be litterally named 'line1.config' etc (and not named after the actual content of the lines), you could do something like:

```
@echo off

set line=0
for /F "delims=" %%a in (file.txt) do call :exec "%%a"
exit /B 0

:exec
set /A line=%line%+1
echo test1.exe -p %1 -f line%line%.config
echo test2.exe line%line%.config line%line%.bin
echo del line%line%.config
exit /B 0
```

Remove the 'echo's if you are happy to do the actual execution.